# ReadFile truncating console input data containing multibyte characters, how to get correct input?

Tags: windows, winapi, console-application, readfile

I was trying to implement a unified input interface using Windows API function `ReadFile` for my application, which should be able to handle both console input and redirection. It didn't work as expected with console input containing multibyte (like CJK) characters.

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole), for console input handles, `ReadFile` just behaves like `ReadConsoleA`. <sub><sup>(FYI, results are encoded in console's current code page, so `A` family console functions are acceptable. And there's no `ReadFileW` as `ReadFile` works on bytes.)</sup></sub> The third and fourth arguments in `ReadFile` is `nNumberOfBytesToRead` and `lpNumberOfBytesRead` respectively, *but* they are `nNumberOfCharsToRead` and `lpNumberOfCharsRead` in `ReadConsole`. To find out the exact mechanism, I did the following test:

```
BYTE buf[8];
DWORD len;
BOOL f = ReadFile(in, buf, 4, &len, NULL);
if (f) {
    // Print buf, len
    ReadConsoleW(in, buf, 4, &len, NULL); // check count of remaining characters
    // Print len
}
```

For input like `字`, `len` is set to 4 first (character plus CRLF), indicating the arguments are counting bytes.
For `文字` or `a字`, `len` keeps 4 and only the first 4 bytes of `buf` are used at first, but the second read does *not* get the CRLF. Only when more than 3 characters are input will the second read get unread LF, then CR. It means that `ReadFile` is actually *consuming* up to 4 logical characters, and *discarding* the part of input after the first 4 bytes.
The behavior of `ReadConsoleA` is identical to `ReadFile`.

Obviously, this is more likely to be a bug than design. I did some searches and found a [related feedback](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/27319e79-04a8-4dc0-8141-b993d7c02371/readfile-on-console-input-can-cause-buffer-overflow) dating back to 2009. It seems that `ReadConsoleA` and `ReadFile` did read data fully from console input, but as it was inconsistent with `ReadFile` specifications and could cause severe buffer overflow that threatened system processes, Microsoft did a makeshift repair, by simply discarding excess bytes, ignoring support for multibyte charsets. (This is an [issue](https://gitlab.com/embeddable-common-lisp/ecl/-/issues/606) about the behavior after that, limiting buffer to 1 byte.)

Currently the only practical solution I have come up with to make input correct is to check whether the input handle is a console, and process it differently using `ReadConsoleW` if so, which adds complexity to the implementation. Are there other ways to get it correct?
Maybe I could still keep `ReadFile`, by providing a buffer large enough to hold any input at one time. However, I don't have any ideas on how to check or set the input buffer size. (I can only enter 256 characters (254 plus CRLF) in my application on my computer, but `cmd.exe` allows to enter 8,192 characters, so this is really a problem.) It will also be helpful if more information about this can be provided.

**Ps.:** Maybe `_getws` could also help, but this question is about Windows API, and my application needs to use some low-level console functions.

Comment: @WildernessRanger You've already answered your question: You need to know. There's no way to reliably discover the character encoding of a stream of bytes that represents text. If you don't know, the best you could do is apply heuristics, like [`IsTextUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-istextunicode) does.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your suggestion! I do need to improve the file input part. But maybe my previous edit, which was mainly in response to the first comment, was kind of off-topic and made the question unclear (now I've changed it).  What I am expecting in the question is how to get console input correct (or ways to get/set the size of console input buffer).

Comment: This might be when you enter Chinese or Japanese characters or use LONG, expand it to wide characters, such as "hello" converted to hexadecimal is 68 65 6c 6c 6f, expanded to 0068 0068 006c 006c 006f, plus the UTF-16 identifier FF FE becomes 12 bytes, so it overflows.
For information about setting the console buffer, you can refer to Microsoft's documentation：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer

Comment: @TongXu-MSFT Maybe that's not the problem. There's no BOM identifier in console input. Also, the BOM identifier is only 2 bytes. But if I limit 100 characters to read and enter 100 dual/tri-byte characters, 100/200 bytes will be discarded.

Comment: @WildernessRanger UTF-16 takes one or two 16-bit code point (2bytes or 4bytes).Check this documentation may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/c-unicode-encoding-conversions-with-stl-strings-and-win32-apis

Comment: @TongXu-MSFT Thanks. But I don't think the problem has much to do with UTF-16, as it's used in `ReadConsoleW`. The problematic functions, `ReadConsoleA` and also `ReadFile`, obviously, use multibyte charsets.